# Can a judge acquit an obviously innocent person who insists on a jury trial?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, acquittal

Jane Doe is charged with a crime. She is obviously innocent, but in court, she insists on a jury trial. Can a judge ignore her demand and acquit her without a jury?

Comment: What prosecutor would prosecute a defendant who is obviously innocent?

Comment: lol. There are thousands of that prosecutor.

Comment: In reality, there are various points in a criminal prosecution at which the defense would routinely move for dismissal.  Are you supposing that this defendant doesn't make those motions?  I'm not sure what happens in that case, other than that Jane's lawyer probably gets disbarred.

Comment: @NateEldredge to avoid the issue of why a lawyer is doing this, let's say Jane is representing herself and due to some misunderstanding of the legal system insists on being tried by a jury.

Comment: In civil cases, a judge can dismiss a claim or enter summary judgment [*sua sponte*](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/sua_sponte), i.e. without the benefiting party requesting it.  I couldn't find any reference to this happening in a criminal case, but I don't know why it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I was mainly wondering if "right to trial by jury" includes "right to waste everyone involved's time by insisting on a jury trial when there is no way you could be convicted."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a judge acquit an obviously innocent person who insists on a jury trial?

Yes. This is part of the doctrine of judicial economy and the requirements of "*[w]ise judicial administration, giving regard to conservation of judicial resources and comprehensive disposition of litigation*". [*Kerotest Mfg. Co. v. C-O-TWO Co.*, 342 U.S. 180, 183 (1952)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1952522342us1801503).

In line with [phoog's comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81704/can-a-judge-acquit-an-obviously-innocent-person-who-insists-on-a-jury-trial#comment176912_81704), it would make no sense for a judge to artificially maintain proceedings where the counterparty (in this case the prosecutor) either withdrew or should have withdrawn.

Comment: This is quite incorrect and a bizarre misreading of the case cited in support, and a good example of why people shouldn't rely on this site for legal advice. A defendant who demands a jury trial is entitled to one, regardless of how one-sided the evidence appears. Depending on the jurisdiction, a judge could unilaterally *dismiss* the charges against the defendant, but the judge may not acquit without holding a trial.

Comment: The exception would be in the case of some petty offense where the defendant has no right to a jury at all. But this doesn't seem to be the situation OP is asking about, and even then, the judge would still have to hold a full trial before entering an acquittal.

Comment: @bdb484 yes, I am asking about a case where there is a right to trial by jury.

Comment: @bdb484 is there any significant difference between a dismissal with prejudice and an acquittal?

Comment: @bdb484 "*This is quite incorrect and a bizarre misreading*". You are wrong in purporting that self-explanatory concepts such as *conservation of judicial resources* apply only in the narrow context of the case mentioning them. My purpose was to acquaint the OP with terms akin to judicial economy. "*A defendant who demands a jury trial is entitled to one*". Yes, but the purpose a *reasonable* defendant has is to avoid penalization, not a vexatious insistence to have a trial (jury or otherwise) despite that the judge considers her innocence is so obvious and/or undisputed.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I am correct in purporting that judicial economy is an aspirational goal and not a rule of law. Judges don't get to acquit people just because it serves judicial economy, and the case you've cited certainly doesn't support the proposition that they can.

Comment: @phoog Yes. An acquittal is essentially unappealable. But the prosecution can appeal a dismissal with prejudice, and if the court granted it because the defendant was obviously innocent, the prosecution would win that appeal. There would likely also be a decent chance of having the case reassigned to another judge, as well.

Comment: @Someone In that case, this answer is very wrong.

Comment: @bdb484 "*Judges don't get to acquit people just because it serves judicial economy*". In the OP's scenario it is not "just because" of judicial economy, but because the defendant "*is obviously innocent*". "*An acquittal is essentially unappealable. But the prosecution can appeal a dismissal with prejudice*". That distinction is irrelevant here because OP nowhere suggests that also the prosecution opposes the judge's decision. You can keep splitting hairs, but in doing so you oftentimes end up departing from the scenario an OP describes.

Comment: @bdb484 "*the case you've cited certainly doesn't support the proposition that they can.*" The excerpt I quoted from *Kerotest* is used also in many controversies that have nothing to do with the issues of duplicative proceedings or closing a case. Two examples are [*Ewing v. DMJJ Construction, Inc.*, (Dist. Court, S.D. CA, 2019)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20190628a73) and [*Flowrider Surf, Ltd. v. Pacific Surf Designs, Inc.*, (2018)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20181227689). Your belief that the excerpt is appropriate only in matters similar to *Kerotest* is plain wrong.

Comment: No, I agree with that. It's a great quote about an important principle. It just isn't the principle that wins out in this scenario.

Comment: @bdb484 The principle is that the defendant "*is obviously innocent*" and the court agrees. Therefore, wasting judicial resources just because the defendant's whim is that her innocence be established only in the form of jury trial is ritualistic and absurd. In other words, it is *unwise judicial administration* when a court accommodates that extent of vexation. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137497/discussion-between-inaki-viggers-and-bdb484).

Comment: You may be right that judicial economy calls for an early disposition of the case. But you are mistaken if you think that judicial economy permits the judge to enter an acquittal. The judge *may* be able to dismiss the case, but even that is iffy. If you were correct, I imagine you would have quoted from a case that said so, rather than a patent case about the Declaratory Judgments Act.

Comment: @bdb484 "*you are mistaken if you think that judicial economy permits the judge to enter an acquittal.*" Once again: It is not judicial economy alone, but also the OP's premise that the defendant "**is obviously innocent**" and which led to the 2nd paragraph of my answer. "*The judge may be able to dismiss the case*" or the judge may enter an acquittal instead, as in [*Smith v. Massachusetts*, 543 US 462 (2005)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/20051005543us4621985) on the basis of statutes akin to [Fed. Rule of Criminal Procedure 29](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcrmp/rule_29).

Comment: You continue to put the obvious-innocence cart before the jury-trial horse. The only way to conclude that a defendant is "obviously innocent" is to hold the jury trial that the defendant demands, which is exactly what happened in *Smith v. Massachusetts* and exactly what Rule 29 calls for.

Comment: But again, if you can find a case where the court says a judge can acquit a defendant without holding a trial, I'd love to see it. Pro tip: check to see if there was a trial before the judge entered an acquittal.

Comment: @bdb484 "*if you can find a case where the court says a judge can acquit a defendant without holding a trial, I'd love to see it*". Fed. Rule Crim. Proc. 29 should be clear enough ("*(a) Before submission to the jury. [...]The court may **on its own** consider whether the evidence is insufficient [...]*"). Also [*State v. Eluska*, 698 P.2d 174, n.9 (1985)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1985872698p2d1741872) favors pretrial judgments of acquittal ("*we believe it appropriate in this type of case to insure that [defendants] are **not put to the cost** and uncertainty of a jury trial*").

Comment: It is understandable, but you seem to misunderstand how Rule 29 motions work. They only happen *during* a trial -- not pretrial. OP's unreasonable defendant still gets the trial she wanted.